# Using an input to refer to an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is there a way to refer to an object by using the input from the user?
Something like this:

```
var item1 = {
    name: "cake",
    price: 100
}

var item2 = {
    name: "scones",
    price: 10
}

function test(){
    var userInput = document.querySelector(".codeInput").value;
    
    console.log(userInput.price);
}







document.querySelector(".test").addEventListener("click", test);
```

If a user enters "item1" then 100 should be logged out. So is there a way to have the string "item1" refer to the object item1?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't use separate variables. Use a single object with keys `item1` and `item2`.

Comment: `{item1: {name: "cake", price: 100}, item2: {name: "scones", price: 10}}`

Comment: Why is the user entering variable names instead of product names like `cake` or `scones`, anyway?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was aware of nesting objects, I just thought that there might be another way.